# Sublime Text 3 - can I enable multiple syntax highlighting in the same document?

Tags: plugins, sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting, usability

In **Sublime Text 3**, is it possible to achieve multiple syntax highlighting in the same document?

I am aware that I can change the syntax of an entire document, using:

- `View => Syntax => [LANGUAGE OPTIONS]`

But I note that when I am (for example) writing a PHP document which also contains:

- HTML
- CSS
- Javascript

**Example:**

```
<?php

$stringVariable_1 = 'String Variable1';        // <= THIS IS PHP

echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>                                // <= THIS IS HTML
<html lang="en-GB">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title Here</title>

<style>

/* CSS STYLES HERE */                          // <= THIS IS CSS

</style>
</head>

<body>

<!-- HTML BODY HERE -->

<script>

/* JAVASCRIPT HERE */                         // <= THIS IS JAVASCRIPT

</script>
</body>
</html>
';
?>
```

that when I *highlight **one** of those sections* and change the Language Option from PHP to one of the others the code-hinting still changes to that Language for the *entire document*.

Is there any way (native feature, plugins etc.) I can straightforwardly indicate to **Sublime Text 3** that different areas of the document are written in different languages?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible to use multiple syntax highlighting in the same document.

Check out the solution to [multiple syntax highlighting in sublimetext 3 with .sublime-syntax file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757055/multiple-syntax-highlighting-in-sublimetext-3-with-sublime-syntax-file-type) by [Marco Mazzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309925/marco-mazzon).

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.